# How do you properly organize data to compute multiple (independent) recursive filters at the same time taking advantage of SIMD instructions?

Tags: optimization, c++, moving-average

I'm processing multiple (independent) [Exponential Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) 1-Pole filters on different parameters I have within my Audio application, with the intent of smooth each param value at audio rate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mParams.GetSize(); i++) {
    mParams.Get(i)->SmoothBlock(blockSize);
}

...

inline void SmoothBlock(int blockSize) {
    double inputA0 = mValue * a0;

    for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < blockSize; sampleIndex++) {
        mSmoothedValues[sampleIndex] = z1 = inputA0 + z1 * b1;
    }
}
```

I'd like to take advantage of CPU `SIMD` instructions, processing them in parallel, but I'm not really sure how I can achieve this.

Any tips?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think this is more a programming than signals question, and would be a better fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: @MBaz I'd like to disagree; the question is about algorithm restructuring of something for superior performance, and I do see a strong DSP component in that (as for IIRs, this typically involves [mathematical transformations](http://www.reanimator.ltd.uk/articles/simdiir) on the coefficients, which surpasses the scope of a pure programming question)

Comment: oh wait, I misread and missed the central point: these filters are independent!

Comment: @markzzz: Are you sure that SIMD instructions are not generated? Take your code to https://godbolt.org/ and compile with `-march=native -O3` and see if SIMD instructions are generated.

Comment: @markzzz: somehow your central code line isn't really valid C, so be a bit careful.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: what is not valid? The double assignment?

Answer (score 1):

usually, SIMD instructions work by loading the values you want to apply the same operation to into a wide register, and then applying the vectorized instruction to it.

Now, collating values from all over memory to end up in one say 256-bit wide register, just to do 8 multiplications at once, probably doesn't pay.

If you, however, are able to decide the in-memory layout of these parallel streams $x_i$ to be *interleaved*, i.e.

\begin{matrix}
x_0[0] & x_1[0] & x_2[0] &\cdots&x_7[0]&x_0[1] & x_1[1]&\cdots &x_7[1] & x_8[2]&\cdots 
\end{matrix}

then you could load the consecutive values into one SIMD register without need for any memory or register shuffling; that would be desirable.

Again, in your specific case I wouldn't expect too much from optimization for SIMD: If a single-tap IIR is already the bottleneck, your application is not CPU, but memory bandwidth bound.

If you just *think* you can speed up your application significantly by speeding up this especially cheap operation: I'm afraid that's rather unlikely; if it's trivial to parallelize on an instruction level, your compiler stands a good chance of doing exactly that, and really, one multiply-accumulate per output sample is pretty idyllic, so I doubt there's much to be done, considering the cost of rearranging numbers to make that work (your API defines samples to *not* be in interleaved order, and your compiler can't do anything about that).

There's other aspects to be looked at; among these are questions like whether `double` is really necessary for what is presumably fixed-point numbers with less than 32 bit of dynamic range.

Comment: I don't need to optimize from 90% to 1%. But since I've somethings like 40 paramters smoothing constantly (because they are modulated at audio rate all the time), it use somethings like 4% of CPU only for smooth. Maybe I can reduce this amount simply pack data in parallel, no?

Comment: 40 different smoothed streams really, from an intuition of mine, sounds like memory bandwidth congestion more than CPU congestion.

Comment: Uhm, not really ! They will be 4 doubles * 40. i.e. 1280 bytes. Quite normal for a non-basic synth...

Answer (score 0):

Intel's [Integrated Performance Primitives](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp#support) library contains DSP building blocks that are optimised for DSP on a number of processors. There are [IIR](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp-library-signal-processing-domain-overview/) specific functions (and more specifically [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-iir-filter-functions)) but you are going to have to get a bit familiar with this library, provided that your hardware is Intel based of course. Other companies probably have similar libraries for their products too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already use IPP, but that's not the problem. Is organize data.

Comment: @markzzz Thanks for letting me know, I am sorry, I did not get that. From the way the question is phrased, I interpreted it as trying to generate code that takes advantage of special capabilities of a processor wherever they exist.